# Add a new line or space depending on pattern

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to do the following.

**Patterns:**

aaaaa.BBBBB - to add New Line after the (.)

aaaaaBBBBB  - to add New Line when see a Caps letter.

aaaaa12345  - to add a space when there is a digit (Output: aaaaa 12345)

12345aaaaa  - to add a space when there is a letter after the digit (Output: 12345 aaaaa)

> **Values:**
>
> Client asked about the 21year planPlease follow up at1234567
>
> **ReGex code need to the following:**
>
> Client asked about the 21 **(space)** year plan**(new line)** Please
>   follow up at **(space)** 1234567
>
> **Result:**
>
> Client asked about the 21 year plan
>
> Please follow up at 1234567.

How do I recognize the pattern and also do a specific replacement be it adding **(space)** or **(newline)**?

Here is the code I use currently:

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With objRegex 
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z0-9])"
        SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
    End With 
End Function
```

[image: Output for above code]

Comment: Please provide some actual input to your function (better yet: the actual call), the expected output and the actual output. That way people may be able to figure out your problem quickly, remember: They are helping you for free!!
And: Please indent your function in a logical manner to make it easy to read for humans. Please check out the markdown help if you do not know how.

Comment: I have made the changes, this is my first time asking a question. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: What are some more inputs? 
You want to insert space if string of digits are before or after a string of characters? (If there is not already a space?)
You want to insert a new line if you find a capital letter in the string? Only once?

Comment: Hello @dgorti, the inputs that my data has are as such: 

aaaaa.BBBBB - to add New Line after the (.)

aaaaaBBBBB - to add New Line when see a Caps letter.

aaaaa12345 - to add a space when there is a digit (Output: aaaaa 12345)

12345aaaaa - to add a space when there is a letter after the digit (Output: 12345 aaaaa)

This could be repetitive for some cells. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two regex replacements. The first one to add spaces between `0a` and `a0` (between a number and a lowercase letter), and a second to create the newline between `aA` and `a.A`.

1. `([a-z])([0-9])|([0-9])([a-z])` and replace with `$1$3 $2$4`
2. `([a-z])\.?([A-Z])` and replace with `$1\n$2`
3. If you want a period added at the end use `$` and replace with `\.`

Try this code:

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim result As String

    With objRegex 
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([a-z])([0-9])|([0-9])([a-z])"
        result = .Replace(strIn, "$1$3 $2$4")
    End With
    With objRegex 
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([a-z])\.?([A-Z])"
        result = .Replace(result, "$1\n$2")
    End With
    SplitCaps = result
End Function
```

Comment: Nice! The period needs to be in the first group `"([a-z]\.?)([A-Z])"`

Comment: @Nicolas Maltais Nice, but can I know why is the new line not reflected in my output. Example: "enrolFollow up" --- the result shows "enrol\nFollow up". Is there something wrong with my Excel settings or ?

Comment: @Slai Thank you for your input. I will amend that as well. Any idea why the output reflect "\n" instead of a new line?

Comment: @Slai i amend it to result = .Replace(result, "$1\r$2") and also result = .Replace(result, "$1\r\n$2") and I did wrap text enable. But it display as aaaa/r/nBBBB.

Comment: @Salleh maybe `"$1" & vbCr & "$2"` or `"$1" & vbLf & "$2"`

Comment: @slai IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much both of you, Slai & Nicolas Maltais